# Finite field extension that is properly contained in a splitting field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

> Let $F$ be a finite field extension of $K$. Then there exists a field $L$ containing $F$ and a polynomial $g(x)\in K[x]$ such that $L$ is a splitting field for $g(x)$ over $K$ and every irreducible factor of $g(x)$ in $K[x]$ has a root in $F$.

Let $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ be a basis of $F$ over $K$. Let $g(x)$ be the product of the minimal polynomials of $v_1,\dots,v_n$ over $K$. Let $L$ be a splitting field of $g(x)$ over $F$. Then $L=F(r_1,\dots,r_m)$, where $r_1,\dots,r_m$ are the roots of $g(x)$.

Since $v_1,\dots,v_n\in \{r_1,\dots,r_m\}$ and $F=K(v_1,\dots,v_n)$, $L$ is a splitting field of $g(x)$ over $K$.

Question:
Are there any example such that $F$ is a proper subfield of the splitting field $L$?

Comment: What about $K = \mathbb{Q}, F = \mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$. Take $g(x) = x^3 - 2$ and notice that $L = \mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3},\zeta_3)$ where $\zeta_3$ is primitive third root of unity.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sorry about putting the wrong tag. The extension is finite but the field is not necessarily finite.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think I am confused about the relationship between the set of roots and the two fields $F$ and $L$. Thanks for your explanation. I had updated the question.

Comment: That's ok. Many users have made that particular tagging mistake. Anyway, Mike's comment has that example. His $F=\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$ consists of real numbers only. The other zeros of $x^3-2$ are complex, so cannot be elements of $F$, and hence $F$ is not the splitting field.